# Custom WP_Query not working with cat parameter

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

My WP_Query is not working when using 'cat' parameter.

Working code without 'cat' parameter.

```
$product_id = get_the_id();
$args = array( 'post_type'      => 'wpc-template',
               'posts_per_page' => -1
             );
$args["meta_query"]= array( array( 'key'     => "base-product",
                                   'value'   => $productId,
                                   'compare' => "IN"
                                 )
                          );
```

Not working with 'cat'

```
$product_id = get_the_id();
$args = array( 'post_type'      => 'wpc-template',
               'cat'            => $templateCategoryId,
               'posts_per_page' => -1
             );
$args["meta_query"]= array( array( 'key'     => "base-product",
                                   'value'   => $productId,
                                   'compare' => "IN"
                                 )
                          );
```

NOTE: i am using custom post type. (plugin's post)

Answer (score 1):

`cat` parameter doesn't exist for `get_posts` if you're using it (you didn't share the query call). In this case use `category` instead. `cat` is a WP_Query parameter only.

See [get_posts documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) :

> Note: The category parameter can be a comma separated list of categories, as the get_posts() function passes the 'category' parameter directly into WP_Query as 'cat'.

If it's still not working, do a var_dump of `$templateCategoryId` and if it doesn't content an integer identifying your category, please share the code where `$templateCategoryId` is defined.

Comment: It was an char.
now converted into Integer, but still not working. i am using WP_Query

Comment: My $args variable looking like "Array ( [cat] => 117 [posts_per_page] => -1 [post_type] => wpc-template [meta_query] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [key] => base-product [value] => 288 [compare] => IN ) ) )"

Comment: If 117 is a valid category id, you should check your meta query. First thing, try `=` as value instead of `IN` for `compare` (you're not sending an Array here but a single value).